# Shopware/Symfony: Trouble with deleting custom line items from database

Tags: php, symfony, line, cart, shopware

I'm facing an issue in Shopware where, after deleting a custom line item from the cart, it successfully disappears from the cart throughout the entire checkout process. However, this deleted custom item still appears in the order_line_item table in the database after the order is completed. This is different from the behavior of main products, which, when removed, are also gone from the database.

```
 #[Route(path: '/checkout/line-item/delete/{id}', name: 'frontend.checkout.line-item.delete', defaults: ['XmlHttpRequest' => true], methods: ['POST', 'DELETE'])]
    public function deleteLineItem(Cart $cart, string $id, Request $request, SalesChannelContext $context): Response
    {
        return Profiler::trace('cart::delete-line-item', function () use ($cart, $id, $request, $context) {
            try {

                if (!$cart->has($id)) {
                    throw CartException::lineItemNotFound($id);
                }

                //if engravings were set find engraving which belongs to product and delete amount in cart
                $engravingLineItemId = $this->engravingLineitemService->findEngravingLineItemId($cart, $id);

                if ($engravingLineItemId !== null) {
                    try {
                        $cart = $this->cartService->remove($cart, $engravingLineItemId, $context);
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        throw $e;
                    }

                }
                $cart = $this->cartService->remove($cart, $id, $context);

                if (!$this->traceErrors($cart)) {
                    $this->addFlash(self::SUCCESS, $this->trans('checkout.cartUpdateSuccess'));
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->addFlash(self::DANGER, $this->trans('error.message-default'));
            }

            return $this->createActionResponse($request);
        });
    }
```

I extended the main delete function from shopware, to delete the custom item as well, when the user wants to remove it. When I dump The cart, after delteing, the Linte-Itme is gone. But it still appears in the database. I also tried to remove the LineItem over the cartPersister, but they still appear in the databse.